# Custom Installer

Tags: installation

Can anybody point me to how I can build a custom installer so if a user clicks on a link in their account this will download a custom installer which will have with it some account details such as the username and password. Using this information it should be able to install an application and configure it to the users account without the user filling in any account details

Comment: We know what an installer is… but what do you want to install, and onto what? As for customizing for customers, suggest you include a config file when you send it to them.

Answer (score 1):

This has very little to do with installs and more to do with build and release management.  Here's how I would go about it:

Design an installer that does whatever you need to do and ultimately has empty USERNAME and PASSWORD properties in the Property table.  Use this as you "seed"  MSI.

Have a build and release property that when a user requests to download the MSI a server side process grabs a copy of the seed MSI and opens the database to perform SQL updates against the property table to implant the username and password values.

Finally present this download to the user.

As you can see, there is the work of actually writing the installer ( which can't possibly be explained or taught as a single question ) and the process of managing it's variation just in time for release ( which also can't be explained since we don't know what your infrastructure looks like and the scope would be massive. )